# Mixed assembly won't load from ILMerge-ed result

Tags: c#, ilmerge

I have a simple program that references [The open-source AlphaVSS library](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaVSS). It contains 3 dlls:

- AlphaFS.dll (IL)
- AlphaVSS.Common.dll (IL)
- AlphaVSS.x64.dll (Mixed)

Now I want to merge my `main.exe` with `AlphaFS.dll` and `AlphaVSS.Common.dll`, leave only `AlphaVSS.x64.dll` on the disk.

So I added an AssemblyResolve event to load AlphaVSS.x64.dll from system32:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args2) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("Loading " + args2.Name);

   string name = args2.Name.Split(',')[0];
   string path = "c:\\windows\\system32\\" + name + ".dll";

   if (args2.Name.StartsWith("AlphaVSS"))
   {
       if (File.Exists(path))
       {
           return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
       }
   }

   return null;
};
```

And I merged the rest successfully:

```
%ILMerge% /v4 /ndebug /out:"$(TargetDir)all-in-one.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetDir)AlphaVSS.Common.dll" "$(TargetDir)AlphaFS.dll"
```

Then I copied only `all-in-one.exe and AlphaVSS.x64.dll` to another computer, and launched all-in-one.exe. The first DLL to load is `AlphaVSS.x64.dll` and it's loaded. Then it tried to load `AlphaVSS.Common.dll` and it's not found.

From ILSpy, The `AlphaVSS.Common.dll` is already merged into the `all-in-one.exe` and loaded. But the mixed assembly `AlphaVSS.x64.dll` is still referencing `AlphaVSS.Common.dll`, so it tried to load it again.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: So on the other computer you have all-in-one.exe (with AlphaVSS.Common.dll inside) and AlphaVSS.x64.dll?

Comment: Does your resolver gets executed when AlphaVSS.x64.dll tries to load AlphaVSS.Common.dll?

Comment: @МаксимКошевой Only all-in-one.exe and AlphaVSS.x64.dll; yes, there's a console output indicating that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers in comments, when you load `AlphaVSS.x64.dll` from the drive, it tries to load `AlphaVSS.Common.dll` (since it references it).

But you already catching it with your custom resolver. And since `AlphaVSS.Common.dll` contains `AlphaVSS` this condition will be true `if (args2.Name.StartsWith("AlphaVSS"))` and your resolver'll try to load `AlphaVSS.Common.dll` from the drive.

What you need to do is modify your resolver to load only `AlphaVSS.x64.dll` from the drive and load `AlphaVSS.Common.dll` from contents of current assembly.

In case of `AlphaVSS.Common.dll` try doing something like this:

```cs
Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => a.GetName().Name == "AlphaVSS.Common")
    .Single();
```